# How to create a view with expand/collapse properties similar to excel

Tags: list

I am new to SharePoint and want to create a list with items which can be expanded/collapsed similar to excel. e.g.
In the attached pic I want to hide the test steps and display the entire test case row by default. If the user wants he/she can click and expand to see the test steps.

[image]

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Please refer the following link that i came across. May be this could be helpful for you. Link - http://www.bitsofsharepoint.com/ExamplePoint/Site/ListExpandTextField.aspx

Comment: Do I need to change any part of the code (any variable or icon names)? It is not working for me. I have a list in Newsletter style and 2 levels of grouping. And do I need to create buttons and link those?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to expand SharePoint item, without customization.
For OOB you can group them together and then see expand/collapse option.
To group items together, 
Click List Ribbon-> Modify View-> Scroll to Grouping-> Select column to Group-> OK

Answer (score 0):

Something very handy that is missing from SharePoint lists when you apply groupping, is the Expand/Collapse all button. Here is a simple js that will expand Level 1 first and then Level 2, but will collapse all at once.

You just need to add a Script Editor web part on the page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isLevel1Expanded = false;
    function expandAll() {
        //$("img.ms-commentexpand-icon").click();
    $('tbody[id*=titl]').each(function (k, v) {
      var elementName = $(this).attr('id');
      var level1RegEx = /^titl[0-9]*-[0-9]*_$/;
      var level2RegEx = /^titl[0-9]*-[0-9]*_[0-9]*_$/;
      if(elementName.match(level1RegEx) && !isLevel1Expanded){
        //console.log('level 1');
        $(this).find("img.ms-commentexpand-icon").click();
        //isLevel1Expanded = true;
      }
      else if(elementName.match(level2RegEx) && isLevel1Expanded){
                $(this).find("img.ms-commentexpand-icon").click();
                //console.log('level 2');
          }
    });
    isLevel1Expanded = true;
    }
    function collapseAll() {
        $("img.ms-commentcollapse-icon").click();
    isLevel1Expanded = false;
    }
    var expandButton = "<a href='#' onClick="
    +'"' + "this.href='javascript:expandAll()'"
    + '">&nbsp;<img title="Expand all groups" style="border:none;" alt="expand all" src="https://hsdatacloud.sharepoint.com/sites/departments/TechnicalServices/SiteAssets/plus.png"></a>';
    var collapseButton = "<a href='#' onClick="
    +'"' + "this.href='javascript:collapseAll()'"
    + '">&nbsp;<img title="Collapse all groups" style="border:none;" alt="collapse all" src="https://hsdatacloud.sharepoint.com/sites/departments/TechnicalServices/SiteAssets/minus.png"></a>';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ms-pivotControl-container").append(expandButton).append(collapseButton);
    });
</script>
```